# Excel Formula To Count Sum of the Cells

Tags: excel

I have this Sheet in which I have hours devoted to particular task which are summed up at the end. Now I want to count the number of cell in which sum of hours is a specific number(e.g. 9. Unable to apply COUNTIF function to get exact results.

Unable to attach the screenshot, but the overview is like this

**Task1       Task2         Task3        Task4        Total**

and I want to calculate how many time particular hours are repeated in "Total" that to in next preceding sheet.

Comment: Can you show us either a table containing your data or possibly a concise screen shot?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using SUMIF or SUMIFS in excel sheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24143515/using-sumif-or-sumifs-in-excel-sheet)

Answer (score 0):

`=countif(C:C,9)` should work where column `c` contains your `sum of hours`

Comment: It works only when I insert this formula in same sheet not  in next sheet and I am doing it in same by selecting range in other sheet

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use the `=COUNTIF` for this purpose.

Try this

```
=COUNTIF(SUM,"Value")
```

Comment: this formula doesn't help at all, but thanks for providing links i found SUMPRODUCT formula quite helpful if i want to count "on which day i devoted total 9 hours" but it is still not working in next preceding sheet